# How to implement constantly working notification service in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, service, push-notification, xamarin.android

Does anybody know a way to implement notification service, which would fulfill these conditions:

- it works constantly and receives notifications even, when application is down. It starts automatically after device reboot and so on.
- notification have actions, which, after user clicks them, performs some method from service (fe: web request) without opening my application or bothering user in any way.

So it's very common functionality, many applications runs services like that (Facebook, Gmail, Tinder...), yet I can't find a way to implement this in Xamarin.

Currently I am working on Android project, and my problems are:

1. How to make notification action lead to service method instead of activity?
2. How to make background service working constantly?

I've tried:

- IntentService and Service, but they are destroyed after application is closed.
- above, started with StartForeground(), but it requires constant notification for the service, which is unwanted.
- Firebase messaging, it receives notifications after app is down, but is simplified way, where I can't program actions or any other aspect of notification.

All help will be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you should consider marking your question as answered if it is the case

Answer (score 1):

One good solution to this problem would be to combine AlarmManager with a Service :
AlarmManager will ensure that your task will be executed regularly, even if your application is closed (and, by adding the right receiver, even after reboot)

Then it can call a service with an intent, and the service can do the job in background

This way, you can have a task to be executed in Background regularly

Just take a look to [AlarmManager documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

Registering an alarm can be done this way (this is Java syntax but equivalent one shoud exist in Xamarin) :

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
...
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR,
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, alarmIntent);
```

And then in your AlarmReceiver (do not forget to declare it in the manifest) you can start, for instance, a IntentService :

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //call your service here
        }
    }
}
```

Note : if you want your task to be executed in background, you could need to use a wake_lock but it would need another thread to explain that